# Running powershell/powercli scripts in VMware VCenter connection automation

Tags: linux, powershell, subprocess, powercli

I'm running a set of powerCLI scripts from Ubuntu to connect to VCenter do a bunch of configuration changes. Every script is invoked via SSH, so it is connecting and disconnecting to the VCenter everytime. This is rather time consuming, is it possible to setup powerCLI/powershell environment to connect to a VCenter automatically? Or, maintain a session of a powerCLI/powershell so remote connections can re-use it? One possibility is to use "screen" command to share the session, but i'm hoping someone has a more elegant idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what's being invoked via SSH? PowerCLI 10 can be used in combination with PowerShell Core so that you can have a native PowerShell and PowerCLI experience on your Ubuntu box without the need for SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerCLI6.5.1 to do most of what you are asking. Install 
from the PowerShell gallery.

Find the Module
Find-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI

Install
Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI –Scope CurrentUser

if you run into an error during installation I fixed it with AllowClobber "-AllowClobber" command

Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI

A couple of examples

Connect-VIServer "Server" -SessionId $sessionId

Connect to a server and save the session ID - $serverObject.SessionId You will be able to restore a existing server connection.

Connect-VIServer "Server" -User user -Password pass -SaveCredentials

Will save the credentials to the credential store. That way you can reuse them and they are encrypted.

See here for more info
https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2017/04/powercli-install-process-powershell-gallery.html

Comment: Does saving credentials work on powershell core yet?

Comment: My challenge is that I'm running powershell on Linux. Despite running latest versions of powershell(6.0.1) and powercli(10.1.1), "SaveCredentials", "Get-VICredentialStoreItem", "New-VICredentialStoreItem", "Remove-VICredentialStoreItem" are still not supported.

Comment: That stinks....I see your issue. I didn't see the Linux keyword in your question.